# Preloader with svg animation for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, svg, preloader

First: [this is my SVG animated with css & js](http://beonik.com) (using SVG Support plugin for wp)

Second: I tried on my localhost to use different preloader plugins for wordpress but I didn't find one that can get my js for animation.
So I came here to you guys to help me do it. Or if you know a good plugin...

After the animation ends I want to have a transition like the one used [here when you go to Studio page](https://3dro.ps/) with 2 background colors.
It is possible to do it for wordpress.

Thanks

Comment: you can do with Ultimate Addons for WPBakery Page Builder and revolution slider pro plugins

Comment: It can be done with SVG as you expected, please check our work http://design-studio.io/

Comment: And we used lottie, may be you can use https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web. We built a Visual Composer addons for WordPress and JS addons for HTML  use

Comment: @TechnoDeviser can you elaborate please. I use these plugins in my theme already. How can I do it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the html code to copy and paste.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}
a{
   color: #e8e8e8;
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 310;
  stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  animation: dash 2s linear  infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  }
 
  25% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 15;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  }
}

.loader {
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from{ transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to{ transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div style=" display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;">
<svg class='loader'
   width="120"
   height="120">
   <circle
    class="progress-ring__circle"
    stroke="#D9DDE4"
    stroke-width="10"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    fill="transparent"
    r="52"
    cx="60"
    cy="60"/>
  <circle
    class="path" 
    stroke="#1a73e8"
    stroke-width="10"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    fill="transparent"
    r="52"
    cx="60"
    cy="60"/>
 
</svg>
  
  <a href="https://codesandbox.io/s/ring-preloader-ui-opeso" target="_blank">[Customize your own ring preloader]</a>
  </div>
```